# Batch script not working with 'prompt method' in Windows NT 4.0, any alternatives?

Tags: windows

i want transform for windows nt 4.0, but i now recognized with helps chatgpt the prompt method not working for this complex batch, any alternative method maybe this os?

```
@echo off
chcp 65001 > nul
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

REM A két mappa elérési útvonala
set "mappa1=C:\temp\hullamteszt\hullam3"
set "mappa2=C:\temp\hullamteszt\hullam4"

REM Keresési fájl neve bekérése
set /p "keresesi_fajl=Adja meg a keresett fájl nevét: "

REM Célkönyvtár
set "cel_konyvtar=C:\temp\hullamteszt\hullam2"

REM Törölje a korábbi listát, ha létezik
if exist "fajllista.txt" (
    del "fajllista.txt"
)

REM Keresse meg a .rcp kiterjesztésű fájlokat a két mappában és listázza őket
for /r "%mappa1%" %%i in (*.rcp) do (
    echo %%i >> "fajllista.txt"
)
for /r "%mappa2%" %%i in (*.rcp) do (
    echo %%i >> "fajllista.txt"
)

REM Ellenőrizze, hogy talált-e fájlokat
set fajlok_szama=0
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%i in ("fajllista.txt") do (
    set /a fajlok_szama+=1
)

REM Ellenőrizze, hogy van-e találat
if %fajlok_szama% EQU 0 (
    echo Nincsenek .rcp kiterjesztésű fájlok a megadott mappákban.
    pause
    exit /b
)

REM Listázza ki a talált fájlokat és kérje meg a felhasználót, hogy válasszon ki egyet
set /a sorszam=0
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%i in ("fajllista.txt") do (
    set /a sorszam+=1
    echo !sorszam!. %%i
)

REM Ellenőrizze a felhasználó választását
set /p "valasztas=Válasszon ki egy fájlt (1-%fajlok_szama%): "
if %valasztas% LSS 1 (
    echo Helytelen választás.
    pause
    exit /b
)
if %valasztas% GTR %fajlok_szama% (
    echo Helytelen választás.
    pause
    exit /b
)

REM Kinyitja a kiválasztott fájlt
set /a jelenlegi_sorszam=0
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%i in ("fajllista.txt") do (
    set /a jelenlegi_sorszam+=1
    if !jelenlegi_sorszam! EQU %valasztas% (
        set "cel_fajl=!cel_konyvtar!\%%~nxi"
        copy "%%i" "!cel_fajl!"
        echo A kiválasztott fájl másolva a célkönyvtárba.
        del /Q fajllista.txt
        pause
        exit /b
    )
)
```

maybe choice.exe or something available for this?
anyway i want prompt for missing file for copy when i prompt and listing the files, then after choiceing the fix dir that will be copying the .rcp file